# map a json object of string arrays to a java class

Tags: java, json

I am trying map a json object of string arrays to a java class.

### json:

```
{ "SKU": ["A", "B", "C"], "Desc": ["Milk", "Bread", "Jam"] }
```

### java class to map json to:

```
public class Inventory_Metrics {
public String[] SKU;
public String[] Desc;
}
```

### json mapping method:

```
@Path("/post")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addInventory(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Inventory_Metrics inv_met = mapper.readValue(json, Inventory_Metrics.class);
    System.out.print(inv_met.SKU[0]);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

### The exception is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/api] threw exception [org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.mycode.database.mapping.Inventory_Metrics out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@182856b6; line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.mycode.database.mapping.Inventory_Metrics out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@182856b6; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: You also need to provide your Inventory_Metrics class source code.

Comment: I still get the same error when I change Inventory_Metrics to:

import java.util.List;

public class Inventory_Metrics {
    public List<String> SKU;
    public List<String> Desc;
    public Inventory_Metrics(){
    }
    public void setSKU(List<String> value)
    {
         this.SKU = value;
    }
    public void setDesc(List<String> value)
    {
         this.Desc = value;
    }
}

Comment: Have you verified that the JSON you are posting is valid? The error seems to suggest that the entire JSON is starting with `[`.

Comment: Yes
{
    "SKU": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ],
    "Desc": [
        "Milk",
        "Bread",
        "Jam"
    ]
}

Results 
Valid JSON

Comment: Solved- Thank you.
I was posting through my browser rather than curl and it was caching an invalid json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off Browser caching of old invalid json post data.